# Two div's in one line(using col-md and col-md-offset Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having two divs:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 "> </div>
<div class = "col-md-3 col-md-offset-9  "></div>
```

It looks like this:[image]

But I need it to look like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6"> </div>
<div class = "col-md-3"> </div>
```

[image]

But I need to use offset.

Comment: Do you have to use twitter bootstrap columns for this? you could easily accomplish this by setting both div's styles to `div {float:left;width:400px;}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The count of columns in an entire row is always 12.

So, in your first code, you're reaching 19 columns therefore this is happening, you need to sum them up to 12.

section 1: offset 1 + width 6 = 7 
then
section 2: offset 2 + width 3 = 5

Total: 12

This should work.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 "> </div>
<div class = "col-md-3 col-md-offset-2  "></div>
```

or anything that adds up to 12.

Answer (score 2):

What are you exactly trying to do? If you want it to look like the second image you can use:

```
<div class="col-md-9"> </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> </div>
```

Or if you want an offset of, say, 3 columns between them, maybe you want something like:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"> </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> </div>
```

If you want less offset, say two columns, increase the size of the first column accordingly, e.g.:

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-2"> </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To show 2 Div's one on the far right and the other on the far left:

CSS:

```
.div1,.div2 {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Inside Body tag:

```
 <div class="div1">Div 1 content</div>
 <div class="div2 pull-right">Div 2 content</div>
```

Notice the `pull-right` bootstrap's class. Alternatively you can use `float:right`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this.

```
class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1"
class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2"
```